# VBA XML: Find root nodes for multiple namespaces

Tags: excel, xml, vba, parsing, namespaces

I've got an XML file with multiple namespaces defined. I'd like to figure out a quick way to identify the root nodes of each different namespaces. I'm looping through various different file sources and I need to move from one namespace to the next.

I've tried the following routine -- which is called by another routine that loads the XML and creates and dimensions the various variables required (xDoc, xRoot, xNS, etc.).

I can't seem to figure out how to easily parse through the namespaces without knowing the prefixes, etc. in advance.

```
Sub CheckNameSpace()

If xDoc.namespaces.Length = 0 Then
    bNS = False
    xOutRng.Offset(x, 0) = "No namespaces present"
    x = x + 1
Else
    bNS = True
    ReDim xNS(0 To xDoc.namespaces.Length - 1)
    For i = 0 To xDoc.namespaces.Length - 1
        xNS(i) = xDoc.namespaces(i)
        xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:nS" & i & "='" & xNS(i) & "'"
        xOutRng.Offset(x, 0) = "Namespace nS" & i & " ="
        xOutRng.Offset(x, 1) = xNS(i)
        x = x + 1
    Next i
End If

Set xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement

Debug.Print xRoot.Prefix
Set xNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//nS0:*")

End Sub
```

Here's one of the sample XML files that I've been trying to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseEnvelope xmlns="http://www.nwabcdfdfd.com/messagin" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                   
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ResponseHeader>
      <RequestId>directv_99e0857d-abf3-461c-913e-3ab59c6b5ef6</RequestId>
      <ResponseId>1162969</ResponseId>
      <MessageVersion>1.10</MessageVersion>
      <RequestTimestamp>2013-02-12T17:26:28.172Z</RequestTimestamp>
      <ResponseTimestamp>2013-02-12T17:26:50.409Z</ResponseTimestamp>
      <SenderId>CarePortal2</SenderId>
      <ProgramName />
      <TestProdFlag>P</TestProdFlag>
      <ResultCode>9</ResultCode>
      <Locale>en_US</Locale>
      <Errors>
         <Error>
            <ErrorCode>9</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorNumber>90001</ErrorNumber>
            <ErrorMessage>System error occurred</ErrorMessage>
            <ErrorFieldId />
         </Error>
      </Errors>
   </ResponseHeader>
   <ResponseBody xsi:type="CPSingleSignOnResponse">
      <PortalUserID>45497</PortalUserID>
      <PartyID>1858186</PartyID>
      <WarrantyItemName>DTV ABC WOLE HE P</WarrantyItemName>
      <WarrantyInventoryItemId>138677</WarrantyInventoryItemId>
      <ClientWarrantySku>202</ClientWarrantySku>
      <ClientWarrantyDescription>DV Plan</ClientWarrantyDescription>
      <ContractNumber>4003564</ContractNumber>
      <IsPortalUserCreated>N</IsPortalUserCreated>
      <IsPartyCreated>N</IsPartyCreated>
      <IsContractUpdated>N</IsContractUpdated>
      <IsFootPrintUpdated>N</IsFootPrintUpdated>
      <Customer>
         <PartyId>185812386</PartyId>
         <Salutation />
         <FirstName>Tejas</FirstName>
         <LastName>Tanna</LastName>
         <AddressList>
            <Address>
               <PartySiteId>3617490</PartySiteId>
               <Type>BILTO</Type>
               <Address1>CASCADES</Address1>
               <Address2>202</Address2>
               <Address3>RIDGE HEAVEN</Address3>
               <Address4 />
               <City>STERLING</City>
               <State>VA</State>
               <PostalCode>20165</PostalCode>
               <County>LOUDOUN</County>
               <Province />
               <Country>US</Country>
               <Urbanization />
               <AddressStyle>US</AddressStyle>
            </Address>
            <Address>
               <PartySiteId>3613791</PartySiteId>
               <Type>SHIP_T</Type>
               <Address1>CASADS</Address1>
               <Address2>22</Address2>
               <Address3>RIE HEEN</Address3>
               <Address4 />
               <City>STELI</City>
               <State>VA</State>
               <PostalCode>2065</PostalCode>
               <County>LOUUN</County>
               <Province />
               <Country>US</Country>
               <Urbanization />
               <AddressStyle>US</AddressStyle>
            </Address>
         </AddressList>
         <PhoneList>
            <Phone>
               <ContactPointId>2371717</ContactPointId>
               <Type>HOME PNE</Type>
               <PhoneNumber>51-62-7464</PhoneNumber>
               <Country>1</Country>
               <PrimaryFlag>Y</PrimaryFlag>
            </Phone>
         </PhoneList>
         <EmailList>
            <Email>
               <ContactPointId>237516</ContactPointId>
               <EmailAddress>a.abc@abc.com</EmailAddress>
               <PrimaryFlag>Y</PrimaryFlag>
            </Email>
         </EmailList>
      </Customer>
   </ResponseBody>
</ResponseEnvelope>
```

Comment: Hello, I've posted a sample XML below. The goal is to be able to read information from the nodes within each names space and I'm trying to write code that is flexible enough to read files where the namespaces and node names aren't known in advance.

Comment: Perfect. That's just what I needed. I've modified your code to be able to loop through and identify all nodes with each namespace used.

Answer (score 0):

While there are other prefixed namespaces, none of the elements in posted XML document have prefixed names. So for purposes of parsing, those namespaces are not needed.

But since you have a single default namespace defined in root without colon-separated prefix (`xmlns="http://www.nwabcdfdfd.com/messagin"`), all underlying descendant elements are encapsulated in it. However, you can still run XPath parsing without referencing any element by name such as `//*`. Below parses every element in document into spreadsheet columns.

```vb
Public Sub ParseXMLElements()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim xmlDoc      As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim xml_document_as_string As String

    ' INITIALIZE AND LOAD XML DOC
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Document.xml"    ' LOAD FROM FILE
    ' xmlDoc.LoadXML xml_document_as_string  ' LOAD FROM STRING
    
   ' PARSES ALL ELEMENTS IN DOCUMENT
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*")           
    
    ' OUTPUT TAG AND TEXT IN WORKSHEET
    With Worksheets("MAIN")                  ' ADJUST SHEET NAME
        i = 1
        
        ' PARSE ALL NODE NAME AND TEXT TO CELLS
        For Each var In xmlNodeList
            .Cells(i, 1) = var.nodeName
            .Cells(i, 2) = var.Text
            
            i = i + 1
        Next var
    End With

ExitHandler:
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlNodeList = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image: Spreadsheet output]